# How do I tell CPAN to install all dependencies?

Tags: perl, dependencies, cpan

How do I tell CPAN to install all dependencies?

I tried setting these in `cpan`:

```
cpan> o conf prerequisites_policy follow
cpan> o conf commit
```

I still had to answer "y" a couple of times (but fewer than before it feels like).

Is there a way to get it to always go ahead and install? I want to make it unattended.

It would seem that I want a flag to always trust CPAN to do the right thing, and if it suggests an answer I would like to follow it (always hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when it asks something).

Comment: Perhaps I should add a feature to my cpan script to set the auto install environment variables based on the CPAN.pm setting. See tsee's answer, which is the other half of the problem.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is the one-liner making these changes permanent including automatic first-time CPAN configuration:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'my $c = "CPAN::HandleConfig"; $c->load(doit => 1, autoconfig => 1); $c->edit(prerequisites_policy => "follow"); $c->edit(build_requires_install_policy => "yes"); $c->commit'
```

Or combine it with `local::lib` module for non-privileged users:

```
perl -MCPAN -Mlocal::lib=~/perl5 -e 'my $c = "CPAN::HandleConfig"; $c->load(doit => 1, autoconfig => 1); $c->edit(prerequisites_policy => "follow"); $c->edit(build_requires_install_policy => "yes"); $c->commit'
```

Run it before using the CPAN shell or whatever.

Comment: isn't it the same as in @sdf anwer?

Answer (score 83):

Try setting PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT like so:

```
PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1 perl -MCPAN -e 'install My::Module'
```

It should make CPAN answer the default to all prompts.

Comment: Any way to make this persistent, so you can just type "install My:Module" into cpan each time and it will remember this?  Edit Config.pm?

Comment: If you're on linux, add the line `export PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1` to your ~/.bashrc

Comment: If you get an error `Can't locate object method "install" via package "xxx" at -e line 1.` add a "+" right before the module name.

Answer (score 60):

The latest and greatest answer to this question is to use [`cpanm`](http://p3rl.org/App%3a%3acpanminus) instead (also referred to as App::cpanminus or cpanminus)!

> DESCRIPTION
>
> cpanminus is a script to get, unpack, build and install modules from
>   CPAN and does nothing else.
>
> It's dependency free (can bootstrap
>   itself), requires zero configuration, and stands alone. When running,
>   it requires only 10MB of RAM.

To bootstrap install it:

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
```

or if you are using [`perlbrew`](http://p3rl.org/App%3a%3aperlbrew) simply

```
perlbrew install-cpanm
```

or from cpan itself:

```
cpan install App::cpanminus
```

From then on install modules by executing (as root if necessary)

```
cpanm Foo::Bar
```

Comment: I have this problem when I use `cpanm`, so telling me to use it is not the solution here.

Comment: rather than a blind comment, please ask as a new question and link here. I suspect a permissions issue might be your problem

Comment: On an Ubuntu 18.04 I installed with `sudo apt install cpanminus make`.

Comment: Down-voting. Don't recommend that people execute the output of curl.

Comment: Up-voting. "The output of curl" is how to install a great MANY things, from k8s to (on some systems) Docker. The curl is used in context of a legitimate project, not random advice to run curl output, but besides that it is out of scope to impose your personal policy here. Be aware you can always save the curl to disk, inspect it then run it.

Answer (score 32):

Changing the following parameter on top of prerequisites_policy follows.

```
cpan> o conf prerequisites_policy 'follow'
cpan> o conf build_requires_install_policy yes
cpan> o conf commit
```

This will change it from "ask/yes" to "yes" and stop it asking you.

Comment: Thanks! I need these two options so that it did not ask me again and again!

Comment: Note that these are the default values for these settings.

Answer (score 28):

Here's what I'm pretty sure you're looking for:

```
cpan> o conf prerequisites_policy follow
cpan> o conf commit
```

Answer (score 6):

Set

```
prerequisites_policy
```

in the configuration.

See [Config Variables](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN#Config-Variables).

Comment: Are the prompts related to downloading module source? If so, see **connect_to_internet_ok** option. Otherwise, tell us what other prompts you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Well all basically, these last ones was "optional modules".

Comment: The problem is things that auto-install on their own. CPAN.pm doesn't get a chance to handle that stuff. See tsee's answer.

Comment: Link now appears to be dead

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's related to [ExtUtils::AutoInstall](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ExtUtils-AutoInstall) or [Module::AutoInstall](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-AutoInstall) being used. Try setting the PERL_AUTOINSTALL environment variable. (Cf. the documentation of those modules.)

Answer (score 4):

I found this to be, by far, the quickest and most reliable way to install CPAN modules:

```
yes | perl -MCPAN -e "CPAN::Shell->notest(qw!install Your::Module!)"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question - the OP wants a way to automatically install dependencies / automatically respond to prompts.

Comment: In fact,  it does install dependencies and automatically responds to prompts. I use it all the time, including this very moment. But  there is a need for a small modification:

`yes|/root/bin/perl -MCPAN -e "CPAN::Shell->notest(qw!install Your::Module!)"`

Comment: What is "`yes`" supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I have only tried a couple of times to modify the settings in that way and have actually found it easier to drop into the `CPAN.pm` shell by giving `cpan` no arguments, then configuring `CPAN.pm` from the interactive prompt:

```
$ cpan
cpan> o conf init
```

This will initiate the `CPAN.pm` interfaces configuration utility. Simply run through it and specify "follow" where you need to (I forget the question offhand), and you should be good to go.

Comment: You can pass specific settings to `init`. For example, `o conf init prerequisites_policy`. That way, you don't have to go through the long initialization process, but still get the friendly prompt for the setting in question

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this for benefit of people who may have come to this page searching for a way to install all module dependencies needed by a particular perl script. I wrote a script for that:

It should be run as `./installdep.pl yourscript.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
`sudo apt install cpanminus`;
while (<>) {
    if (/USE /i)
    {
        my $line=$_;
        $line=~ s/\s//g;
        $line=~ /^(.*)\./;
        $line=~ s/\;//;
        $line=~s/^USE//i;
        $line=~s/lib.*//i;
        $line=~s/feature.*//i;
        $line=~s/strict//i;
        $line=~s/warnings//i;
        $line =~ s/^(.*)\(.*/$1/;
        unless ($line eq '') {
        my $cmd='sudo cpanm '.$line;
        print "Installing $line \n";
        open my $cmd_fh, "$cmd |";
        while (<$cmd_fh>) {
          print "$_";
        }
        close $cmd_fh;
        print "\n";
    }
    }
}
```

This will use cpanminus to install all module dependencies required by your script. If cpanm isnt installed, it will install it.