# How do I update all my CPAN modules to their latest versions?

Tags: perl, cpan

How do I update all my CPAN modules to their latest versions?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

An alternative method to using `upgrade` from the default CPAN shell is to use [`cpanminus`](https://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/lib/App/cpanminus.pm) and [`cpan-outdated`](https://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanoutdated/bin/cpan-outdated).

These are so easy and nimble to use that I hardly ever go back to CPAN shell. To upgrade all of your modules in one go, the command is:

```
cpan-outdated -p | cpanm
```

I recommend you install `cpanminus` like the docs describe:

```
curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

And then install `cpan-outdated` along with all other CPAN modules using `cpanm`:

```
cpanm App::cpanoutdated
```

BTW: If you are using `perlbrew` then you will need to repeat this for every Perl you have installed under it.

You can find out more about `cpanminus` and `cpan-outdated` at the Github repos here:

- https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus
- https://github.com/tokuhirom/cpan-outdated

Comment: why using such extra tools while there's a built-in solution (see second answer)?

Comment: "why using such extra tools" While it's outside the scope of the OP's question, cpanimus DOES solve the problem of CPAN asking you to press Enter and/or type [y]es. Afaict you can not _reliably_ suppress this behavior with vanilla CPAN. This becomes important as soon as any kind of cron or CI server is involved, and/or if you like to be able to start an upgrade with the confidence it won't hang while you're out getting coffee (which in my experience is often the case with vanilla CPAN) See also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898782/how-do-i-tell-cpan-to-install-all-dependencies

Comment: [root@portal-test bugzilla-4.4.4]# cpan-outdated -p | cpanm
Can't locate object method "new" via package "LWP::UserAgent" at /usr/bin/cpan-outdated line 170.

Comment: @eav Because it's more "nimble"!  The built-in solution (CPAN shell) does not work well in limited memory hence why Miyagawa originally developed cpanminus - https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus#Another-CPAN-installer

Comment: @sharif - Need more info... what versions of cpanminus, cpan-outdated, LWP and Perl are you using?

Comment: perl v5.8.8. LWP 5.805. centos 5.10 final

Comment: Those are old (perl dates from 2006, LWP from 2005).  Ideally you need newer version of both.  If for some reason you can't do this then I would upgrade LWP version by version until you got cpanm|cpan-outdated working. NB. IMPORTANT - If you are using the CentOS installed Perl then don't use CPAN or CPANMINUS with these!  Never mix with OS packages!!  Instead use Perlbrew to brew your own perl (and then use cpanminus etc within this).

Comment: I like this solutions because you can easily run `cpan-outdated -p` first to see what it is going to do before actually running the upgrades.   It isn't clear how to do a dry run with `cpan upgrade`

Comment: I tried using this to update packages for imapsync, only to find that `cpan-outdated -p` didn't actually list any of the modules used by imapsync. Manually updating them with `cpanm` worked.

Answer (score 62):

An easy way to upgrade all Perl packages (CPAN modules) is the following way:

```
cpan upgrade /(.*)/
```

cpan will recognize the regular expression like this and will update/upgrade all packages installed.

Comment: Okay, this isn't as _cool_ as `cpanminus`, but at least you don't have to download anything to get this to work.

Comment: For those having problems with this command;  Try running cpan shell via `cpan`, and then run the `upgrade /(.*)/` in the cpan shell.

Answer (score 40):

For Strawberry Perl, try:

```
cpan -u
```

Comment: For regular Perl too. From the man page: `-u  Upgrade all installed modules. Blindly doing this can really break things, so keep a backup.`

Comment: The option `cpan -u` how long does it take to update?

Answer (score 20):

Try `perl -MCPAN -e "upgrade /(.\*)/"`. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 18):

[`upgrade`](http://p3rl.org/CPAN#upgrade-Module-Regexp-...)

BTW there is a `help` command.