# How you maintain Perl packages installed with cpanm?

Tags: perl, cpan

I use [cpanminus](http://cpanmin.us) to install Perl packages to userspace, but i have not found idiomatic way to maintain packages afterwards. How you update, delete (with dependencies) and get overview of listed packages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727795/how-do-i-update-all-my-cpan-module-to-their-latest-versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cpan-outdated](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?cpan-outdated). The man page has clear instructions for how to use with cpanminus.

Comment: Some way to get rid of all unwanted packages with dependencies?

Comment: No. I do not think that any of the CPAN tools maintains state to decide why a module was installed (explicit request or to fulfil requirement) nor is there any static tracking of how many installed modules depend on a given module.

Comment: My solution is to keep track of modules I need in a number of [Task](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Task) inspired metapackages and then install all modules from scratch now and then. But I am also using [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) for regular updates of perl itself.