# How to upgrade all perl CPAN modules installed in a user directory?

Tags: perl, cpan

I have a user directory with CPAN modules and I want to have a script that will upgrade all of the to their latest release.

Note: it should be executable by any user not only root.

What is the proper command to do this?

I know that `cpan -r` should upgrade CPAN modules but I want to force it to do this only for those installed in this specific directory.

Comment: How did you install those modules ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is of any help, but perhaps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727795/how-do-i-update-all-my-cpan-module-to-their-latest-versions

Answer (score 1):

`cpan-outdated` can help you.

https://metacpan.org/module/cpan-outdated

upgrade all versions installed:

```
cpan-outdated | cpanm
```

upgrade modules installed in a specified dir

```
cpan-outdated -lextlib | cpanm -lextlib
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ~/perl5/lib &&
find -name '*.pm' \
| perl -ple's{^\./}{}; s{/}{::}g; s{\.pm\z}{};' \
| xargs cpan
```