# How to install dropbox-api?

Tags: perl

Hey guys i am trying to install the dropbox-api onto my suse 11.4 but i keep getting this error:

Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3 /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3 .) at /root/bin/dropbox-api line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/bin/dropbox-api line 6.

At first i thought it lacked some perl modules so i go ahead and install some CPAN modules along with the CPAN shell using #perl -MCPAN -e shell
so through the shell i install the extra modules like # install DateTime::TimeZone 
But still i get the same error does anyone know what i could be doing wrong or whats wrong?
I am using the instructions on this link to install the api

https://github.com/s-aska/dropbox-api-command

Comment: What does "perl -MDateTime -e'print DateTime->VERSION'" print?

Comment: There is even shorter version to check some module version: "perl -MDateTime\ 999"... In your case either to module is not installed or is installed to some PATH which is not in the @INC array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`At first i thought it lacked some perl modules so i go ahead and install some CPAN modules along with the CPAN shell using #perl -MCPAN -e shell so through the shell i install the extra modules like # install DateTime::TimeZone`

The error states that the module [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.70/lib/DateTime.pm) isn't installed, [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.70/lib/DateTime.pm) is not [DateTime::Timezone](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-TimeZone-1.35/lib/DateTime/TimeZone.pm). Install the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.70/lib/DateTime.pm) module

Comment: Thanks guys. It seems that its just the modules are not installed as pointed out by Raoul. i am installing them one by one. Incase i come up to another huddle that i fail to solve i will let you guys know. but thanks for the help.

Comment: @roykasa if you're installing via CPAN you can configure it to install all dependencies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898782/how-do-i-tell-cpan-to-install-all-dependencies