# Can't locate Module/Build.pm in @INC perl build

Tags: perl

I am trying to run build a Perl project. When I try perl Build.PL, I get an error:

Can't locate Module/Build.pm in @INC

I installed CPAN and tried `cpan Module::Build`. However when I do that I get an `error: Can't locate Module/Metadata.pm in @INC`

I tried installing metadata but tests are failing. Is there a way to install Build.pm and all its dependencies at one go

Comment: Your question of how to install dependencies is already extensively answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898782/how-do-i-tell-cpan-to-install-all-dependencies
Another possibility mentioned in one of the answers there is to use `cpanm`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install a module with dependencies you need to set the following in cpan:

```
cpan> o conf prerequisites_policy 'follow'
cpan> o conf build_requires_install_policy yes
cpan> o conf commit
```

Comment: Note that those are the default values for those settings.