# "Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm in @INC" during git build

Tags: git, perl, docker, build, autotools

I'm building `git` on a pretty minimal system (Ubuntu 16.04 docker image) without using the package manager (except for `wget`, `xz-utils`, `make` and `gcc`). I thus installed prerequisistes as follows:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install --yes wget xz-utils make gcc
wget http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.26.1.tar.gz && tar xf perl-5.26.1.tar.gz && cd perl-5.26.1 && ./configure.gnu && make -j16 && make install && cd ..
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/gettext-0.19.8.1.tar.xz && tar xf gettext-0.19.8.1.tar.xz && cd gettext-0.19.8.1 && ./configure && make -j16 && make install && cd ..
wget https://www.zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz && tar xf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz && cd zlib-1.2.11 && ./configure && make -j16 && make install && cd ..
cpan install ExtUtils::MakeMaker
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.13.3.tar.gz && tar xf git-2.13.3.tar.gz && cd git-2.13.3 && ./configure && make -j16 && make install && cd ..
```

However, `make` in the `git` source root fails due to

```
Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm in @INC (you may need to install the ExtUtils::MakeMaker module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at Makefile.PL line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 3.
make[1]: *** [perl.mak] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'perl.mak' failed
make: *** [perl/perl.mak] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:1870: recipe for target 'perl/perl.mak' failed
```

I'm aware that there're a lot of solutions regarding `Can't locate [module].pm in @INC` for perl projects, [How do I tell CPAN to install all dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898782/how-do-i-tell-cpan-to-install-all-dependencies). However, `git` uses GNU autotools and options which could fix the issue are probably read from environment variables which I couldn't figure out so far.

The Ubuntu 16.04 provides a `perl`, but no `cpan` command (which is why I added the `perl` source installation). After the `perl` source installation is recognized, but doesn't seem to be used:

```
$ which -a perl
/usr/local/bin/perl
/usr/bin/perl
$ which -a cpan
/usr/local/bin/cpan
```

After `cpan` I get

```
$ find / -name MakeMaker.pm
/builds/project-0/perl-5.26.1/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm
/builds/project-0/perl-5.26.1/cpan/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm
/root/.cpan/build/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.32-0/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm
/root/.cpan/build/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.32-0/blib/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.26.1/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm
$ perl -E 'say for @INC'
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.26.1/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.26.1
```

The setup is abstracted from a bootstrapping script, so using the package manager is really no option.

You can use `docker run -i -t ubuntu:latest` in case you care to investigate the environment.

I provided a reproducible build at https://gitlab.com/krichter/git-docker-build and example output of the GitLab CI runner can be found at https://gitlab.com/krichter/git-docker-build/-/jobs/53888412.

Comment: Where is `MakeMaker.pm`? Is its directory in `perl E 'say for @INC'`? Have you tried running `cpan ExtUtils::MakeMaker` first, on its own?

Comment: Your Git install seems to be running with perl-5.22 (pre-installed on 16.04) whereas you installed perl-5.26. I am not sure to which installation your `cpan` command belongs.

Comment: @Borodin I added the output of `perl -E 'say for @INC'`. Replacing `cpan install ExtUtils::MakeMaker` with `cpan ExtUtils::MakeMaker` doesn't help (I assume that's what you meant).

Comment: @amon I added more info about initial perl and cpan commands to the question (there's a `perl`, but no `cpan` command provided, i.e. `cpan` has to belong to the `perl` source installation). Nevertheless autotools are picking up `/usr/bin/perl` instead of `/usr/local/bin/perl`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm unclear why you have two copies of `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` within `/usr/local/lib/perl5`. What do you get from `perl -MExtUtils::MakeMaker -E 'say for values %INC'`?

Comment: @Borodin I found a solution (see my answer below). Thanks for your support. You can investigate further yourself with the SSCCE I provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `./configure --with-perl=/usr/local/bin/perl` for `git` works, however it's unclear for me why `/usr/local/bin/perl` isn't picked up before `/usr/bin/perl` if `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`.

The `cpan ExtUtils::MakeMaker` isn't necessary after adding `--with-perl`.

Comment: Ah! I was about to suggest removing the original installation of perl or taking its location out of `PATH`. Well done.

Comment: If your regular programs are `/usr/local/bin/perl` and `/usr/local/bin/cpan` but git is using `/usr/bin/perl`, then modules missing in the git build can probably be installed with `/usr/bin/cpan`.

Comment: @mob `/usr/bin/cpan` belonging to `/usr/bin/perl`) doesn't exist (see question). Or do you mean to install everything into prefix `/usr` instead of `/usr/local` and effectively overwrite the `perl` provided by the system? That's not a good idea, right?

Answer (score 38):

In CentOS7, I encounter this issue, I find I should install the `perl-devel` firstly:

```
yum install perl-devel
```

Then retry it.